# How to Default to a different method upon debugging in a web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working with a Solution I did not write. The creator of this solution attempted to create 2 projects, but they are both ran from the same project, if that makes sense. As in both "project" files are within the same Visual Studios Project. The different projects are just called by using a different starting method within the Home controller. I'm trying to get project 2 to run so I can debug it, but it keeps defaulting to project 1. I've been modifying the properties: "Project Url", "Start URL", "Override application root URL", but nothing is working. What do I need to do to get the appropriate method in the home controller to be called?

I'm not sure what other details would be helpful, so please let me know if I'm missing any crucial details.

```
namespace MainProject.Controllers{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult project2Index()
    {
         // Do stuff for proj2
    }

    public ActionResult project1Index()
    {
         //Do stuff for Proj 1
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, right click on project 2 and click "Set as StartUp Project"

Comment: So, that's the hard part. There are 2 "projects", but they are in the same "Visual Studios Project". You call one by specifying in the URL which method to call in the Home Controller: "Project1Index()" or "project2Index()"

Comment: Not sure how it would be helpful. I'll put the skeleton of the code in the question, but I've been running in debug and I'm still not even touching Project2Index

Comment: You have the action and controller, the url to access Project2Index should be something like http://<your project root url>/home/Project2Index